# How to align an element properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems keeping this element in correct alignment when resizing browser. The problem is that when I make the browser smaller the element size shrinks from left to right when I want it to shrink right to left. This is so the left border always stays in the same place relative to browser size. Below is my code

**HTML**

```
</div>
  <div class="content2">
    <h4><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>
    {{ article.excerpt | strip_html | truncatewords:70 }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.content2 {
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 850px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What does "correct alignment" mean? Centered horizontally?

Comment: I just want it to always shrink from right to left rather than left to right when resizing the screen so that the left hand side of it is always in the same position no matter what the browser size is